# Can I force the bot to respond with embeds with the author's name if {0.author} doesn't work? (Discord.py)

Tags: python, discord, bots

Can I force the bot to respond with embeds with the author's name if {0.author} doesn't work?

```
    if message.content.startswith('Привет'):
        print('[command]: Задан вопрос3 ')
        embed = discord.Embed(color=0x9d00ff)
        embed.title = '**Привет {0.author}!**' 
        embed.description = '**Привет {0.author}!**'
        await message.channel.send(embed=embed)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you’re trying to use [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format), but you’re not calling `format`.

After the strings that reference `0`, call `.format(message)`.

I also recommend looking into f-strings, which can be a more intuitive (and faster) way of formatting data in strings.